# how to make multiple column base on multiple category of values of a column in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
['Expenses','1.   Interest Expense','1.1  On Deposit Liabilities','1.1.1  Saving Account','1.1.2  Fixed Account','1.1.2.1  Up to 3 months Fixed Account','1.1.2.2  3 to 6 months Fixed Account','1.1.2.3  6 months to 1 year Fixed Account','1.1.2.4  Above 1 year Fixed Account','1.1.3  Call Deposit','1.1.4  Certificate of Deposit','1.2  On Borrowing','2.   Commission Expense','3.   Staff Expense','4.   Office Operating Expenses','5.   Foreign Exchange Loss']
, columns=['level1'])`

my desire output is [image]

Comment: can you show us some sample data ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460653/how-to-extract-single-column-into-multi-column-in-python?noredirect=1#comment95729253_54460653  this is the sample @Wen-Ben

Comment: Better show us your dataframe not picture . And also that is why your previous question did not get an answer .

Comment: import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
['Expenses','1.   Interest Expense','1.1  On Deposit Liabilities','1.1.1  Saving Account','1.1.2  Fixed Account','1.1.2.1  Up to 3 months Fixed Account','1.1.2.2  3 to 6 months Fixed Account','1.1.2.3  6 months to 1 year Fixed Account','1.1.2.4  Above 1 year Fixed Account','1.1.3  Call Deposit','1.1.4  Certificate of Deposit','1.2  On Borrowing','2.   Commission Expense','3.   Staff Expense','4.   Office Operating Expenses','5.   Foreign Exchange Loss']
, columns=['level1']) this is my dataframe @Wen-Ben

Answer (score 1):

If your entries are in a `list` of `string` you can use

```
[x.split()[0] for x in columns]
```